# IndexError: list index out of range, how can I delete an object in a list?

Tags: python, list

I just started with learning python.

I want to remove the last number of each row, how can I do that without getting an error?

```
data = [[144, 128, 183, 0],
[208, 87, 125, 0],
[233, 176, 196, 0],
[4, 190, 163, 0],
[249, 95, 211, 1]]
```

there are 489 rows but I shortened it for better readability.

```
x = 0


for datapoints in range(489):
    data.remove([x][3])
    x += 1

print(data)
```

Comment: last numbers means ` 0 0 0 0 1`

Comment: yes, how do i delete them?

Comment: `[i[:len(i)-1] for i in data]` create a new list excluding the last item

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pop method for every sublist in the list.

```
data = [[144, 128, 183, 0],
[208, 87, 125, 0],
[233, 176, 196, 0],
[4, 190, 163, 0],
[249, 95, 211, 1]]
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i].pop()
print(data)
```

OUTPUT

```
[[144, 128, 183], [208, 87, 125], [233, 176, 196], [4, 190, 163], [249, 95, 211]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `list comprehension`

```
[i[:len(i)-1] for i in data]
Output:
[144, 128, 183],
 [208, 87, 125],
 [233, 176, 196],
 [4, 190, 163],
 [249, 95, 211]]
```

In case you wat to use `del`

```
for datapoints in range(len(data)):
    del data[datapoints][-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner with list comprehension (not necessary to specify the number of rows):

```
[sublist[:-1] for sublist in data]
```

Where -1 is the last element in the sublist, and [:-1] specifies you want to include all elements *until* that element (non-inclusive).